# Sort multidimensional object literal array by external value

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array, sorting

I am trying to make a homemade line of sight for a game im building which is a gridbased, 2D top-view board game. The board has divs in a 2-dimensional array which are all black and will be transparent if the player is in a corridor which are also in a 2-dimensional array with objects. There are miscellaneous blocks in the corridors and i need to take them into consideration so the divs will stop getting transparent if they appear in the corridors where the player is.

So i've got an idea to sort the array of objects in a given corridor where the player is located by the x,y values.

```
corridors[i].sort(
    function(a)
    {
        if(a.y > playerObj.position.y && a.x > playerObj.position.x) return 1;
        if(a.y < playerObj.position.y && a.x < playerObj.position.x) return -1;
        return 0;
    });
```

But this does not seem to work. The changing of the divs background-color to transparent is still beginning from the array's first index. I want it to start from the players position in the corridor and work itself outwards like so:

O is simply a tile, P is the player, X is the tile that has just been made transparent

OOOOOOOOOOOPOOOOOO

OOOOOOOOOOXPOOOOOO

OOOOOOOOOOXPXOOOOO

OOOOOOOOOXXPXOOOOO

But for this scenario to function i need to find how to sort my array correctly, and i hope you can help me with this. The examples i've seen on the net has parameters a and b, so is it not possible to use an external variable? Should i perhaps create the players position as a new object and push it to the array and then sort the array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so i think i solved it. I simply made the sorting function be stored in a new array and used that instead.